# How to add another project to an existing android project using gradle (Not using android studio)

Tags: android, gradle

I have two projects with directory structure as follows

```
./MyProject
./SomeOtherProject
```

and i want to add **SomeOtherProject** to **MyProject** by writing the directory structures to gradle. (Am not using android studio)

e.g when I add **AnotherProject** to libs directory

```
./MyProject/app/libs/AnotherProject
```

then I add this to **./MyProject/app/build.gradle**

```
api project(':app:libs:AnotherProject:app')
```

The project is successfully imported.

Now I have project directory structure

```
./
./MyProject/
./SomeOtherProject/
```

and I want to add **SomeOtherProject** to **MyProject** by hard coding to the build.gradle files

I have tried this but its a failure, projectis still not imported.

**./MyProject/settings.gradle**

```
include ':app';-
include ':SomeOtherProject';-
project(':SomeOtherProject').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../SomeOtherProject/app');-
```

Then in my **MyProject/app/build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
implementation ':SomeOtherProject'
}
```

I have also tried this in **./MyProject/app/build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
api project(':app:..:SomeOtherProject:app'
}
```

If question is not clear, I will update, please help.:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this to your **./MyProject/app/bulid.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    api project(':..:SomeOtherProject:app')
}
```